# Core.Command.run : API changed between v0.14 and v0.15?

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-core

The following code that was compiling successfully with Core v0.14 (ocaml 4.10), but fails with v0.15 (ocaml 4.11).

```
open Core;;
let command = Command.basic ~summary:"essai" (
  let open Command.Let_syntax in
  let%map_open s = anon(sequence ("n" %: int))  in 
  fun () ->
    List.iter s ~f:(fun x -> Printf.printf "n = %d\n" x ) ;
  )

 
let () = Command.run ~version:"0.0" ~build_info:"RWO" command;;
```

The error (with 4.11) :

```
File "cli.ml", line 10, characters 9-20:
10 | let () = Command.run ~version:"0.0" ~build_info:"RWO" command;;
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
Error (alert deprecated): Core.Command.run
[since 2021-03] Use [Command_unix]
File "cli.ml", line 10, characters 9-20:
10 | let () = Command.run ~version:"0.0" ~build_info:"RWO" command;;
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type [ `Use_Command_unix ]
       This is not a function; it cannot be applied.
```

The documentation of Core.Command.run states that it is obsolete - but I fail to find how to replace it.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with the compiler version. This is a library API change, and libraries usually aren't tied to specific version of the compiler. Even if they were they'd still have their own version number, so why not refer to that?

Comment: fully correct  ! - I checked the core.opam files for each of both version, those 2 versions are respectively dependent of ocaml 4.08 and 4.11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`Command_unix`](https://ocaml.org/p/core_unix/v0.14.0/doc/Command_unix/index.html) as indicated by the message you received. Documentation link for [`Command_unix.run`](https://ocaml.org/p/core_unix/v0.14.0/doc/Command_unix/index.html#val-run).

Comment: not really ;)... I wrote the code following https://dev.realworldocaml.org/command-line-parsing.html - and, according to this doc, Command.run is supposed to parse the command line arguments.  But it looks like it is no more the case, and that Command_unix.run is rather used to execute a linux commands (or so) if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

The core library has been restructured in version 0.15: Unix-specific modules and functions have been moved to the `core_unix` library in order to make the main `core` library more portable (or at least javascript compatible).

The function `Command_unix.run` in `core_unix` library is exactly the same as the `Command.run` function in previous versions of the `core` library.

Comment: thx for the answers. indeed it works - I was facing some difficulty to write the dune file.